# Grails 2.0.1 Dependency Dropdown

Tags: grails

I want to know if anyone has developed a dependency dropdown like Country and State in Grails 2.0.1 without using prototype. Appreciate snippets of code

Answer (score 0):

You can just use remotefunction and g:Select, something like

```
<g:select 
      onchange="${remoteFunction(
                  controller:'example', 
                  action:'country',
                  update:'state', 
                  params:'\'country=\'+$(\'#country\').val()' }" 
name="country" ... />
```

http://alexduan.com/2011/02/17/grails-jquery-and-ajax/